# Do I need a new computer to try to the Vulkan API?

Tags: vulkan

I really want to try out the vulkan api but I am not sure of an easy way to test it. I just want to draw some triangles and stuff. I currently own a 3 year old computer. You think it is possible without buying a new one?

I am new to graphics and only had some previous knowledge with openGL and WebGL

Comment: update your graphics driver and see if vulkan is present. Otherwise you would only need to change graphics card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I'm using 5 years old PCs (Intel i5-3470 and i7-3770 - both from 2012), coupled with ageing NVidia GTX 650 Ti Boost (2013) video card. Despite the age, it runs Vulkan, OpenGL up to 4.5 and DirectX 11 titles very well.

So, age is not a concern, as long you have a good GPU and updated video drivers. Hardware upgrade is almost impossible for notebooks, but desktop can use cheap nVidia or AMD video cards and have reasonable 3D capability.

I advice you to update you video driver and install Vulkan SDK. The SDK will install the required runtime drivers. After this step, you can check your Vulkan capabilities using Sascha Willems' [GPU Info](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/), **or** SDK's *vkjoson_info.exe*, which generates a .json text file.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing your secifiations, especially your GPU, it is very hard to tell if you need a new PC.
Nontheless there is a list of hardware supported by Vulcan that might help:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API)#Compatibility

As stated by ratchet freak there is an up to date list which can be found here:
https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products#vulkan